# Actually delete versus delete flag for many-to-many tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This question has been asked many times regarding entity tables.

What about a many-to-many (aka cross, join, pivot, etc, etc) table?

For instance, I have entity tables "courses" and "students", and a many-to-many table "students_taking_courses".

What are the pros and cons of deleting the joining record versus adding a flag column to the table and marking it as being deleted?  What conditions would make one approach preferred over the other?

EDIT.  Please assume the the two entity tables have surrogate primary keys.

Comment: Please comment why you think this should be closed, and I will edit to try to improve.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming usage of RDBMS, when having a flag instead of physical delete:

- We will keep full trace of actions in the system. When having a
  history is crucial this approach will be beneficial.

On the other hand

- By keeping records, we will need more space
- There will be more updates, in heavy load or high concurrency systems
  that may be a problem.
- More complexity will be imposed to the design, think about when we
  need to force a unique constraint to `course-student` (many to many)
  table, showing a course can be taken by a student once in a term.
  Having the flag, we will need more effort than using DBMS unique
  constraint. 
  I prefer an [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) approach for historical data over using the flag.

Comment: The conflict with unique constraints is an important issue.  Designing for historical data is much more complicated than just adding a status flag to a table.